# question about map sort

Tags: c++

for example we have map

```
map<char,int>mymap;
mymap['a']=101;
mymap['c']=45;
mymap['b']=76;
mymap['d']=98;
```

i know that if we  iterate  through  map it will print element  according to following way

```
a>=101;
b>=76;
c>=45;
d>=98;
```

how do such that small keys  refer small values? or

```
a-45
b-76
c-98
d-101
```

?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you do not want to permanently associate values at all, you're wanting to order two different sets of values, and then line them up together at some point. In which case, do not use a std::map. You want two different std::set (or multiset if you want to allow duplicate values) which orders the values separately. Then iterate through the two together at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do it on your own, map does not iterate over values like that.  One option is to use a second map where the keys and values are swapped (if you can have duplicate values, use a multimap).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using boost multi-index for that, less overhead than using two sets/maps and roughly the same speed.